# Are there more implementations of encapsulation?

Tags: oop, encapsulation

What I knew about encapsulation in OOP is that it refers to the restriction to the access of some data of an object. I thought that we mainly achieve encapsulation by the usage of access modifiers and properties inside of a class that allow us to validate the data before exposing it to the outer classes but in [this article](https://www.sumologic.com/glossary/encapsulation/) it's written that encapsulation also refers to bundling of data and functions into a single unit which is achieved by using/creating a class.

Honestly this is something I was not aware of until now and I am curious if there is a concrete definition of what encapsulation is and also I want to ask: Are there more examples and usages of encapsulation than using properies, classes and access modifiers?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `Are there more examples and usages of encapsulation than using properies, classes and access modifiers?` in Objective-C you can encapsulate some definitions/declarations by just moving them to the implementation file. (You don't do the same in other C-like languages because you can't have definitions of the same things partially in multiple places there)

Answer (score 1):

As wiki says about encapsulation:

> encapsulation refers to the bundling of data with the methods that
> operate on that data, or the restricting of direct access to some of
> an object's components. **Encapsulation is used to hide the values or
> state of a structured data object inside a class, preventing direct
> access to them by clients in a way that could expose hidden
> implementation details or violate state invariance maintained by the
> methods**.

And an example of encapsulation can be:

```
public class Pizza
{
    private decimal cost;
    public decimal Cost() { return cost };
}
```

`cost` field is encapsulated. You have a method `Cost()` to get value of `cost` variable.